# What must I do to access my own public method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created folders in my project named Classes, Forms, and Models.

Let's say my project is named ABC, so the folder hierarchy is:

```
ABC
    Classes
    Forms
    Models
```

In \Models\, I have a class named ApplicationModel.cs, which contains a public method named GetApplications().

However, when I call that method from elsewhere in the same ABC project, I get, "The name 'GetApplications' does not exist in the current context"

I've added:

```
using ABC.Models;
```

to the calling class, but it makes no difference. I right-clicked GetApplications() to hopefully see "Resolve" there, but no go.

What must I do to access my own public method?

Comment: Is the method static?  If not, do you have an instance of ApplicationModel to call the method on?

Comment: The `using` statement has nothing directly to do with folders; it has to do with namespaces.  There is a common convention in which the folder structure and the namespace structure mirror one another, but that's just a convention.  To what namespace does ApplicationModel belong?  Can you show the call site where you're getting the compiler error?

Comment: @ChrisShain calling static methods on an instance (or vice versa) does not result in the "... does not exist in the current context" error.

Comment: @phoog I wasn't implying that it did.  I was trying to make the OP clarify what his intention was.

Comment: @ClayShannon I'm glad my answer solved your problem, but it would be nice if this question could include what the problem actually was. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the definition of `GetApplications()` and the code that's attempting to call it, but I assume it's either a [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.100).aspx) or an instance method of the `ApplicationModel` class. In either case, you may have made your code aware of the namespace of the `ApplicationModel` class with the using statement, but the method must either be called on the class or an instance of the class, like so:

If `GetApplications` is a static method,

```
var applications = ApplicationModel.GetApplications();
```

If it's an instance method:

```
var appModel = new ApplicationModel(); // or, retrieve the instance from elsewhere...

var applications = appModel.GetApplications();
```

One way or another, you must refer to the class containing `GetApplications` in order to call it. If this doesn't help you solve the problem, please edit your question to contain the definition of the method, and the calling code.

Comment: This would not explain the "... does not exist in the current context" error.

Comment: @phoog Assuming the OP is merely calling the method without referencing the class or an instance thereof would indeed explain that error. Without seeing the call site - as you mentioned in your comment - I can only make an educated guess about what's causing the problem. I'll edit my answer as needed given the OP's elaboration.

Comment: @phoog In other words, I can only assume the OP is calling the method as `var x = GetApplications()`, as though it were declared locally.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using a static function. Did you forget the static keyword?

A static function "runs" from a class, not an object:

```
public static string[] GetApplications()
```

Comment: This would not explain the "... does not exist in the current context" error.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to give definitive advice without some code on how you are trying to call that method.  I can think of two possible ways:

- either you are trying to call the method via the `ApplicationModel` *class*(`ApplicationModel.GetApplications()`), in which case you need to declare the method `static`
- or you need to call the method on an object, but you are using the type -- in this case declare/create an object of type `ApplicationModel` and call the method on that object; (e.g. `ApplicationModel model = new ApplicationModel(); model.GetApplications();`)

Comment: This would not explain the "... does not exist in the current context" error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the class is not marked as public.

You class should be

```
   namespace ABC 
  {
    namespace Models
    {
        public class ApplicationModel  //class needs to be public is accessed outside the namespace
        {

        }
    }
  }
```